# How do I install Pillow on my mac without pip?

Tags: data-transfer

I installed python using homebrew. It didn't come with pip, so I'm having trouble getting pillow installed. I tried to get xcode and build it from the source, but I can't get xcode because it requires software version 1.14 (or whichever the newest version is), but my macbook doesn't update to this. How do I get pillow?

Answer (score 1):

You can install [pip very easily](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) (Though I think it should come with most python builds now.) using the following commands:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

In fact, you shouldn't even need homebrew to install python. You can get the latest versions of python 2 and python 3 as [macos installer packages](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/). Even without installing python, MacOS does include an (old) version of python 2.7 by default.

Once you've installed pip, you can type:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Also, I think you should still be able to [download a version of Xcode compatible with your OS version](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).